# Visual Studio designer shows wrong property value

Tags: visual-studio, properties, c++-cli, designer

In my user control I have a public property:

```
public: property System::Double Maximum;
```

Now, if I put the control on a form and set the value of "Maximum" in the designer to -3.5 or a similar value, the control and visual studio behave as expected.

But every time I restart visual studio or reload the form project, the value in the designer is changed to 3.5 but the value in the code is still -3.5.

This problem only occurs with negative doubles or floats with minimum one decimal place. (-2.0 stays -2.0, -1.5 becomes 1.5)

I have already tested visual studio 2008 team edition and visual studio 2010 express edition. I have also changed the type of the property to System::Single and have defined a private member variable to hold the value.

Any ideas?